# Make R use C notation when escaping terminals

Tags: c, r, cran

Not sure I am using the right terminology here, but I need the `print` or `deparse` methods use C notation (e.g. `"\x05"` instead of `"\005"` ) when escaping bytes out of the regular character set.

```
x <- "This is a \x05 symbol"
print(x)
[1] "This is a \005 symbol"
```

Is there a native way to accomplish this?

I need this for generating BSON: http://bsonspec.org/#/specification. All of the examples explicitly use `\x05` notation.

Comment: FYI, both `"\x05"` and `"\005"` are valid C syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacking into the internals of `print` seems a bad idea. Instead I think you should do the string escaping yourself, and eventually use `cat` to print the string without any extra escaping.

You can use `encodeString` to do the initial escaping, `gregexpr` to identify octal `\0..` escapes, `strtoi` to convert strings representing octal numbers to those numbers, `sprintf` to print numbers in hexadecimal, and `regenmatches` to operate on the matched parts. The whole process would look something like this:

```
inputString <- "This is a \005 symbol. \x13 is \\x13."
x <- encodeString(inputString)
m <- gregexpr("\\\\[0-3][0-7][0-7]", x)
charcodes <- strtoi(substring(regmatches(x, m)[[1]], 2, 4), 8)
regmatches(x, m) <- list(sprintf("\\x%02x", charcodes))
cat(x, "\n")
```

Note that this approach will convert octal escapes like `\005` to hexadecimal escapes like `\x05`, but other escape sequences like `\t` or `\a` won't be affected by this. You might need more code to deal with those as well, but the above should contain all the ingredients you need.

*Note* that the BSON specification you refer to almost certainly meant raw bytes, so as long as your string contains a character with code 5, which you can write as `"\x05"` in your input, and you write that string to the desired output in binary mode, it shouldn't matter at all how R prints that string to you. After all, octal `\005` and hexadecimal `\x05` are just two representations of the same byte you'll write.

Comment: Ugh. I was hoping for a more native solution. But I guess this works.

Answer (score -1):

Does `cat` suit your needs? Note, you have to escape the backslash:

```
> x <- "This is a \\x05 symbol\n"
> cat(x)
This is a \x05 symbol
```

Comment: You string does not contain the actual character. It just contains an escaped backslash. I need this for large text files which contain actual `\x05` characters